# How can I get bluetooth headphones to connect automatically when they are turned on?

Tags: bluetooth

How can I get my Bluetooth headphone to connect automatically when I turn them on? They do that on KDE Plasma and with my phone, but not on Ubuntu 18.04. They are paired and working, but I have to open Bluetooth settings every time and connect them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around for a solution to this and tried a couple of scripts. What worked in the end was adding the following to /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 for my headphones.

Turns out this did NOT work. After a reboot pulseaudio refused to start. When I tried to start it manually I got:

E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Module "module-switch-on-connect" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.

What am I missing? How can I get automatic connection and have the module load only once?